# =~ function arguments in reverse order

Tags: regex, haskell

`Bool > "my left foot" =~ "foo" :: Bool`

`=~` is an infix operator from `Text.Regex.Posix` package and here, the target string is on the left and the pattern string is on the right. Here, `=~` makes sense to me.

But here,

```
readIp = untilM (=~ "[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}")
    (putStr "Enter IP address: " >> getLine)
```

`=~` is curried with its right argument only and given to `untilM`. `target string` is given as the last parameter. How does `untilM` ensure that `=~` is passed the target string on its left and the pattern string on its right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just how operator sections work.

```
(=~)    = \x y -> x =~ y
(x =~)  = \y -> x =~ y
(=~ y)  = \x -> x =~ y
```

Mnemonic: when you have `(x =~ y)` and you take out the `x`, you are left with `(  =~ y)`.

If you wanted the read a regex and match it against a constant string, you would use the other section:

```
untilM ("foo" =~) (putStr "Enter regex: " >> getLine)
```